# Distinguish Magic mouse/Trackpad scroll event

Tags: macos, iokit, cgeventtap

Inside an Event Tap I need to distinguish the scroll event that comes from a magic mouse to that which comes from a TrackPad.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Is there a way to get the product ID of the generating device from the CGEvent? Can IOkit help me here?